# How to include static files in partial templates in Hugo

Tags: javascript, html, go, hugo, static-site

I am learning hugo. I want to include the static css & js files in my partial directory under layout directory.

IF i access like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title> Home </title>
</head>
<body lang="en">
```

The CSS file is not included. The files are under static->css->bootstrap.min.css

Comment: As long as bootstrap.min.css is in /static/css, the posted code should work.